# Is PHP the only popular language that mixes simple and associative arrays into a single type?

Tags: php, arrays, programming-languages

I'm doing a research on PHP and wondering if there any other commonly used programming langues that use an associative array for both simple indexed element storage and key-value functionality. Does it make PHP unique in this sense?

Comment: AFAIK, Lua uses "tables" for both lists and dicts.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does the same thing - see [Arrays on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Did a test with JS http://ideone.com/K3t3tB Treating arrays as associative arrays doesn't work for me. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Thought about JS as well, but it seems to miss an `array` type altogether ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fx34v/)), where as PHP [differentiates](http://3v4l.org/GtB3H) between `array` and `object`

Comment: In Javascript, the equivalent for associative arrays are objects.  Or conceptual value objects (objects only containing values instead of methods).

Comment: @Flosculus Bit confused. So JS does *not* mix simple and associative arrays together in a *single* type or does it

Comment: I'm still not convinced. Reading up on [ECMA Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), they only speak of "_array objects_" where an array is a special kind of object - not something else. This explains why `typeof` would return object. And so I would argue that JS (or ECMAScript dialect for that matter) are not equal to PHP in this case.

Comment: In JavaScript, arrays are *special* objects.  JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays", per se.  It has objects, which can use ints/strings as keys, and arrays which are numeric.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/associative-arrays.html

Actionscript as well, but the same can be expected from any dialect of Ecmascript.

EDIT: AS3 took a more strict approach.

Regarding JS:

An object in JS can have a property with a numerical name `{0:'value'}`.

The difference there is you can only access it as an array `obj[0]`, whereas `{'name':'value'}` can be accessed like `obj.name` or `obj['name']`.

Arrays do exist in JS, but they are only numerically indexed, but both objects and arrays can be treated the same, in a `for loop` for instance.

Comment: Wrong example. In AS3, there are two different types, the associative arrays (described in your link) and [simple arrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html)

Comment: But you can make an associative array / map / dictionary behave like an array in almost any language using integer values as keys for values. How does it make JS any different? Thanks anyway.

Comment: In that respect PHP is not that much different either, you can still iterate over an objects public properties.  Although in PHP arrays by default are numerical, they can skip indexes, implying that even numerical arrays are at their core still associative.